# Percentile rank equal to zero?

Tags: statistics

Data is 5, 7, 13, 9, 6; What is percentile rank for a score of 4?

When I plug in all the information into the equation for percentile I get zero?
Is this possible?

Comment: The reason you get 0 is because no body got a score of 4.

Comment: @Angad a score of $4$ or lower*